# How can I solve this integer part question?

Tags: radicals

I am trying to understand this problem but my textbook does not offer a good explanation,it asks what the integer part of the square root is.

$\sqrt{n^2+6n}$    , $n \in N$*

Comment: Hint: find an integer $k$ (in terms of $n$) such that $k^2 \le n^2 + 6n < (k+1)^2$ (this may only work for "large" $n$). Hint2: it is better if you state specifically where you don't understand/do not agree with the presentation of the solution in your book, or we might give the same solutions as your book and fail to help you.

Comment: Well it was on how they got to (k+1)^2 because I knew that [x] is defined as k<= x <= k+1

Comment: More precisely $[x]$ is defined as the integer $k$ where $k \le x < k+1$. Taking squares we have $k^2 \le n^2+6n < (k+1)^2$. Now I see your question is how they got the answer $k = n+2$. The way I would go about it is by completing squares: $n^2+6n = n^2 + 6n + 9 - 9 = (n+3)^2$, so $k$ is close to, but cannot exceed $n+3$.

Comment: Ok,but then I am left with k and n ,do I replace k with [n^2+6n]? Because then I would get the integer part of x squared for which I cannot do nothing to....

Comment: From $k^2 \le n^2 + 6n < (k+1)^2$ we can take square roots to obtain $k \le \sqrt {n^2+6n} < k+1$. This satisfies the definition of $[n^2+6n]$.

Comment: Ok I now understand the question ,thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The integer part of the square root is what you would get if you performed the root operation normally and then chopped off the decimal digits, leaving behind an integer.

For $n\ge2$,
$$(n+2)^2=n^2+4n+4\le n^2+6n<n^2+6n+9=(n+3)^2$$
So the integer part is $n+2$ if $n\ge2$. (For $n=1$ the integer part is $2$.)

Comment: But how did you get to (n+2)^2 and (n+3)^2 ?

Comment: that is what is unclear to me

Comment: @ROBOTICS If the expression can be bounded between two consecutive squares, we know that the integer square root must be the lower value.

Comment: $n^2+6n=(n+3)^2-9$ and the square root must be close, but smaller than, $n+3$. Then compare to $(n+2)^2$.